# Excel 2013 Why is standard deviation not evenly stretched to both sided up and down?

Tags: excel, graph

I calculated data in Matlab.
Now I want to format it in excel.
The values in first row represents some average values. The values in second row represents standard deviation.
I try to draw a graph, but standard deviation bars do not strech up and down evenly, as they should.
I want to achieve graph like this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_bar

[image: Screenshot, how standard deviation is displayed]

I am using Microsoft Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Etko-slowk

It is VERY important you delete all the data, when you set custom values from both textboxes (after you click specify values).